# Hundreds of millions of rows: Index by composite BIGINT, VARCHAR, or CHAR of HASH?

Tags: innodb, index-tuning, primary-key, mysql-5.7, index-design

Given the following:

**Target platform**: MySQL 5.7, using InnoDB.

**Scenario**: Storing hundreds of millions of email addresses (plus some properties not used in queries). All queries will be done by knowing the email address beforehand.

**Proposed solution**:

1. SHA256 the email address.
2. Shard "the email table" by taking the first 3 bytes of the ASCII SHA256, creating 4096 tables (from 0x000 to 0xFFF) that will act as buckets for the email addresses. This tries to avoid having one single huge table.

**Question**: Which of the following would be a good PK to use inside each one of those 4096 buckets in terms of performance (indexing as being more important than querying)? Use of disk space might not be that important upfront (unless there are some heavy arguments to take this into account, which I'm open to know and discuss, of course).

1. VARCHAR(255) of the email address? This is of course the simplest.
2. CHAR(64) of the ASCII SHA256 hash of the email address? Long shot: I'm considering that indexing and comparing fixed length strings (CHAR) is faster than variable length strings (VARCHAR).
3. Split the SHA256 into 8 64bit integers, then create a composite PK of 8 BIGINT columns and index/query by those 8 BIGINT columns instead of using a VARCHAR/CHAR? Crazy idea: Perhaps using only 64bit integers for indexing and querying can provide a noticeable improvement in index and query performance (and also perhaps in disk access/storage). Although this is a composite PK of 8 BIGINT columns :\

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you considered partition by hash?

Comment: Yes, partitioning by the first bytes of that hash is the first part of the proposed solution. Then, the question itself is about choosing the PK inside each one of those partitions. Thanks!

Comment: I am under the impression that you are manually creating the tables, what I meant was something like: `create table email_adresses (email varchar(255) not null, email_hash int as ( cast(conv(substring(md5(email), 1, 16), 16, 10) as unsigned integer) ) ) engine = innodb partition by hash (email_hash) partitions 12`.

Comment: @Lennart I completely missed that feature! Thank you :) I can then avoid creating the partitions manually as you say, and also choose which partition to query. But don't you think the question still stands somehow? How will each one of these partitions scale when they contain a few dozen millions of rows each one? Don't I need to still choose a PK for them (and to use in my queries) like explained in the question? If not, perhaps I'm missing something else. Thanks!

Comment: I.e: In your example, the PK will be an integer, and that's fine, but taking only the first few bytes of that hash can still make some email addresses "fall" in the same bucket/partition, how would the WHERE clause look like to get only one of those emails and not others?

Comment: Not sure I understand your remark, of course there will be more than one email in each partition. If you are looking for a specific email `WHERE email = ?`

Comment: Great! It's just that in your example, I don't see "email" defined as a unique key or pk for those partitions (or any kind of pk at all). If I query by email, but that's not part of the index, how that will affect performance with a few millions of rows per partition? I can't query by "email_hash" either, as that's also not a key, and it only has part of the hash.

Comment: Ah, it should be that. I have not tried it. Anyhow, i just wondered if you concidered builtin partitionin before building your own. It may not fint your needs

Comment: Yes, I am now, as long as I can figure out these matters :) Thank you for suggesting it, I did not know about it.

Comment: Guys, remember KISS.

Answer (score 1):

There is no advantage in any form of `PARTITIONing` based on what you have said.

The simplest, most obvious, index is also the best:  Have the `PRIMARY KEY` be the email address (if it is unique), or *start* with the email address plus something to make it unique.

This is possible

```
id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT -- for uniqueness
...
PRIMARY KEY(email_addr, id)  -- id tacked on for uniqueness
INDEX(id)  -- to keep A_I happy.
```

What makes you think that "one huge table" is a problem?  No, `PARTITION BY HASH` does not buy you anything.

You said "shard" and mentioned 4096 buckets.  Technically that means you have 4096 servers to put parts of the data on.  I assume you really meant `PARTITION` or (yuck) 4096 manually-handled tables, which is limited to a single MySQL instance.

If you really did mean spread across multiple servers, then, sure, the bottom chunk of the SHA256 is a good idea.  MD5 is probably faster and just as good for this purpose.  I would then use a dictionary lookup with 4096 elements to point to however many servers you currently have.